# Solidity: Return a mapping from inside a struct

Tags: arrays, struct, mapping, solidity

here is my code:

```
pragma solidity 0.7.4;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

mapping(uint => ProductWithBids) public internalProducts;

struct SecretBids {
        uint values;
        bool fake;
        string secret;
    }

struct ProductWithBids {
        uint id;
        string name;
        uint price;
        address payable owner;
        address payable beneficiary;
        bool purchased;

        mapping(address => Bid[]) bids;
        mapping(address => SecretBids[]) nakedBids;
        // Allowed withdrawals of previous bids
        mapping(address => uint) pendingReturns;

        uint bidsCount;

        bool ended;
        uint biddingEnd;
        uint revealEnd;

        address highestBidder;
        uint highestBid;
    }

function getNakedBids(uint _id)
    public
    view
    returns(SecretBids[] memory product) {
        ProductWithBids storage selectedProduct = internalProducts[_id];
        return selectedProduct.nakedBids;
    }
```

i need to return the nakedBids but i get the following error :
TypeError: Return argument type mapping(address => struct eShop.SecretBids storage ref[] storage ref) is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) struct eShop.SecretBids memory[] memory.
return selectedProduct.nakedBids;

I get what the error means, i think i have tried everything and looked everywhere. From what i have found is that solidity doesn't support at all this action .Does anyone has any idea what i can try next? If i missed any other important code parts let me know. Thanks in advance.

I also tried :

```
returns(mapping(address => SecretBids[]) memory nakedBids)
```

but then i get the following error:
Types containing (nested) mappings can only be parameters or return variables of internal or library functions.
returns(mapping(address => SecretBids[]) memory nakedBids) {
^-----------------------------------------------^
,TypeError: Type mapping(address => struct eShop.SecretBids[]) is only valid in storage because it contains a (nested) mapping.
returns(mapping(address => SecretBids[]) memory nakedBids)

ps: if i change it to storage it complains that Data location must be memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pretty much gave up on the idea of creating a getter. So i got the data i needed in a more direct way. Probably is not the best way but it worked for me. Feel free to share any other solutions.
Here is the code:

```
    function reveal(
        uint _id
    )
    public
    payable
    {
        ProductWithBids storage selectedProduct = internalProducts[_id];
        //onlyAfter biddingEnd && onlyBefore revealEnd
        require(block.timestamp > selectedProduct.biddingEnd);
        require(block.timestamp < selectedProduct.revealEnd);
        uint count = selectedProduct.bidsCount;

        uint[] memory values = new uint[](count);
        bool[] memory fake = new bool[](count);
        string[] memory secret = new string[](count);

        for (uint i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            values[i] = selectedProduct.nakedBids[msg.sender][i].values;
            fake[i] = selectedProduct.nakedBids[msg.sender][i].fake;
            secret[i] = selectedProduct.nakedBids[msg.sender][i].secret;
        }

        revealInternal(
            values,
            fake,
            secret,
            _id
        );
    }
```

I did not go from the start with this solution because i needed the react-js to do it from the front-end and then just pass it in revealInternal(...);

Answer (score 1):

By the way, you should move `mapping(address => SecretBids[]) nakedBids;` out of the struct, and let it be a storage variable on its own.

`nakedBids` is an array of `SecretBids` struct.

My answer is based on solidity v0.5.x (hopefully similar to 0.7.4). Return array of struct is not supported in solidity yet. Instead you can return tuple.

```
returns (uint[] memory, bool[] memory, string[] memory)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time Ming but i need nakedBids to stay inside the struct.